# Apache running static content and flask app

Tags: python, apache, mod-rewrite, wsgi

I have a Flask app running via `wsgi`.

To lesson the load on my app, which loads a lot of stuff, I would like to serve up my home page, or root url via apache, but I am getting conflicts trying to send "/" a static index file via apache, and then everything else to `wsgi`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.yada.com

    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/yada/static
    <Location /static>
        SetHandler None
    </Location>

    WSGIDaemonProcess yada
    WSGIScriptAliasMatch /.+ /home/ubuntu/yada/wsgi.py

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/yada>

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/$ /static/html/index.html [L]

        WSGIProcessGroup postwire
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

See the AddHandler/mod_rewrite solution at end of section:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive